# Linux Bash: Use awk(substr) to get parameters from file input

Tags: linux, bash, awk, substr

I have a .txt-file like this:

```
'SMb_TSS0303'   '171765'    '171864'    '-' 'NC_003078' 'SMb20154'  
'SMb_TSS0302'   '171758'    '171857'    '-' 'NC_003078' 'SMb20154'
```

I want to extract the following as parameters:

-'SMb'

-'171765'

-'171864'

-'-' (minus)

-> need them without quotes

I am trying to do this in a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
file=$1

cat "$1"|while read line; do
  echo "$line"
  parent=$(awk {'print substr($line,$0,5)'})
  echo "$parent"
done

echos 'SMb
```

As far as I understood awk substr, I though, it would work like this:

```
substr(s, a, b)=>returns b number of chars from string s, starting at position a
```

Firstly, I do not get, why I can extract 'Smb with 0-5, secondly, I can't extract any other parameter I need, because moving the start does not work.
E.g. $1,6 gives empty echo. I would expect Mb_TSS

## Desired final output:

```
#!/bin/sh

file=$1

cat "$1"|while read line; do
  parent=$(awk {'print substr($line,$0,5)'})
  start=$(awk{'print subtrs($line,?,?')})
  end=$(awk{'print subtrs($line,?,?')})
  strand=$(awk{'print subtrs($line,?,?')})
done

echo "$parent"    -> echos SMb
echo "$start"     -> echos 171765
echo "$end"       -> echos 171864
echo "$strand"    -> echos -
```

I have an assumption, that the items in the lines are seen as single strings or something? Maybe I am also handling the file-parsing wrongly, but everything I tried does not work.

Comment: you should [edit] your question to remove the unnecessary parts and focus on what you've tried, the input, the output & the expected output. ATM it's very unclear

Comment: I though, I need to show, how I make my .txt-file. Maybe, the problem can by solved by creating it differently? I really have no plan, where I can start to fix my problem, but I will try to make it more clear

Comment: ping me when you edit your question.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I am still "new" to Stack Overflow, how does pinging work? I hope tagging with @ works as well

Comment: @Shushiro should each item be outputted on separate line? Post the final output

Comment: assuming from your question @RomanPerekhrest, is it so, that I can access the entries in the line as items? I think, I did not fully get, WHAT my line is then. I though of it as one big string, but it actually is more like a list? But to also answer your question, if I could get every item as one line, I think I can then adress it to a variable and that would solve my problem? Then, the answer is yes :)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest output posted, sorry, I overread it when commenting. I am searching a way, to get the parameters I mention in the question. But I think, I am not fully getting awk(substr) or I am not fully understanding the structure of my .txt-file

Comment: but all those variables will be overwritten with each next line, only values from the last line will be outputted, what's the benefit?

Comment: I hope to be able to use the parameters for a curl request. If I do it in the loop and save my result in a file, it should work for all lines, shouldn't it?

Comment: but before digging into curl POST (never did that, only simple gets), I wanted to at least have, what I need :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really unclear exactly what you're trying to do. But I can at least help you with the `awk` syntax:

```
while read -r line
do 
    parent=$(echo $line | awk '{print substr($1,2,3)}')
    start=$(echo $line | awk '{print substr($2,2,6)}')
    echo $parent
    echo $start
done < file
```

This outputs:

```
SMb
171765
SMb
171758
```

You should be able to figure out how to get the rest of the fields.

This is quite an inefficient way to do this but based on the information in the question I'm unable to provide a better answer at the moment.

Comment: thank you. If you check earlier versions, my final goal is curl, but I did not want to post it here, since I did not dig into it yet and dont want others to do my work. If you are interested, I need to obtain information from a website in the end. The parameters are needed to get the right information. I only once used curl with a simple get request for the http-response code. So now, I think, I need POST, and I need the variables for it

Answer (score 1):

the question was orignally tagged python, so let me propose a python solution:

```
with open("input.txt") as f:
    for l in txt:
        data = [x.strip("'").partition("_")[0] for x in l.split()[:4]]
        print("\n".join(data))
```

It opens the file, splits the lines like `awk` would to, considers only the 4 first fields, strips off the quotes, to create the list. Then display it separated by newlines.

that prints:

```
SMb
171765
171864
-
SMb
171758
171857
-
```

Comment: thanks everybody for your time and effort! I will do my best to ask better questions!